# Mapping a LED strip to a matrix where strip lenght and height are dissimilar

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, led

I am trying to address a 36 x 48 LED matrix, but the LED strips are 64 LED long. So, I have to snake the LEDs around the matrix. I have to then address each strip 1 by 1. I can't think of a way(other than mapping the array by hand) to model this array in Python. I didn't explain it well so here are some visuals.

```
example data (where strip = height)
pixel_vals=
{strip_1:[[1] [2] [3] [4] ]   1 2 3 4
strip_2:[[1] [2] [3] [4] ]  = 1 2 3 4
strip_3:[[1] [2] [3] [4] ]}   1 2 3 4

vs how its actually setup (where strip != height) ▼▲◄►■
1 1 2 2   strip_1:[[1] [2] [3] [4] [5]]   ▼ ► ▼ ■
2 5 3 1 = strip_2:[[1] [2] [3] [4] [5]] = ▼ ■ ▼ ▲ (block represent end of a strip)
3 4 4 5   strip_3:[[1] [2]]               ► ▲ ► ■
```

Comment: "I didn't explain it well" Indeed. Sorry but your visuals leave me just as puzzled as to what's going on...

Comment: Create an LED class and fill a 36x48 list of lists with LED instances. They can hold the light settings and the address (strip, index).

Comment: Please explain the layout of the strips in a rectangle. Without this info, we can't help you.

Comment: Do you want to map X/Y to Strip/LED index or conversely ?

Answer (score 0):

A basic idea might look like the following code. Each inner element will contain a tuple with the number of the LED strip and the number of the LED on that strip.

```
x = 36
y = 48
PIXELS_PER_STRIP = 64

matrix = []
for pixel in range(x * y):
    if not pixel % 5:
        row = []
        matrix.append(row)
    row.append(divmod(pixel, PIXELS_PER_STRIP))
```

Let's have a look at the result with the data from your example.

```
x = 3
y = 4
PIXELS_PER_STRIP = 5
```

This will give us

```
[[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)],
 [(0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 0)],
 [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)],
 [(1, 4), (2, 0), (2, 1)]]
```

That looks quite good, but we need the "snake effect". So we reverse every second row.

```
for row in matrix[1::2]:
    row.reverse()
```

Result:

```
[[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)],
 [(1, 0), (0, 4), (0, 3)],
 [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)],
 [(2, 1), (2, 0), (1, 4)]]
```

If you need to transpose the data then use a final

```
matrix = list(zip(*matrix))
```

Result:

```
[((0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1)),
 ((0, 1), (0, 4), (1, 2), (2, 0)),
 ((0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 3), (1, 4))]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

From your enigmatic description, I seem to infer that you fill four columns (height 48) with three strips (total of 192 LEDs), zigzagging. More specifically, using 0-based indexing, the strips fill the following segments:

- (0, 0) to (0, 47), then (1, 47) to (1, 31);
- (1, 32) to (1, 0), then (2, 0) to (2, 31);
- (2, 32) to (2, 47), then (3, 47) to (3, 0).

This block repeats nine times.

Things get much simpler if you flip every other column by the substitution `if X & 1: Y= 47 - Y`. Now you have to map a 36 x 48 array to 27 x 64. This can be done by turning X, Y to a single number, N = 48 * X + Y, and decomposing with S = N // 64, L = N % 64. You can easily figure out the reverse transformation.